# Android call logs handling

Tags: android

How to delete a particular contactno (taken from the user via EditText) from call logs programmatically ??

let me elaborate.
I have created a EditText Field with Delete Button. User will enter the mobile no. and as soon as user hits Delete button, the entered mobile no should be removed from the CallLogs.

Please Help.

thank you

Answer (score 0):

u have following permission in manifast.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
```

Deleting Calllogs for particular number try this way:

```
public void DeleteCallLogByNumber(String number) 
  {   
     String queryString="NUMBER="+number; 
     this.getContentResolver().delete(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI,queryString,null);
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes i have tried this, but i am getting some runtime exception.